# Form is not validated before call javascript function

Tags: javascript, forms, jsp

Below is my simple jsp form where i need to validate the whether the branch number is empty before doing the ajax call.

```
<body>
<div id = "divOrderuserinputContainer">
<table align="center" id="table">
    <form id="orderform" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="POST">          
        <td class="label">Branch Number:
            <input type="text" name="branch" ></input>                  
        </td>       
    <td>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="addData(); return false;"></input>
    </td>
    </form>
 </table>
 </div>
</body>
```

Below is my javascript

```
function validateForm(form) {
var x = document.forms["orderform"]["branch"].value;
if (x == "") {
    alert("You must select a valid Branch branch");
    return false;   
}
}
```

If i remove the return false; in the submit input it does populate alert form the branch input but it still calls the addData(). How to validate the form before call the function addData().

Answer (score 0):

when you click on your submit button, your function addData will be called first and then your validateForm function. If I understood right, you want to validate the form on submission and then call your addData if everything is okay! In this case you can do this:

```
<body>
<div id = "divOrderuserinputContainer">
<table align="center" id="table">
    <form name="orderform" id="orderform" onsubmit="return validateForm();" method="POST">          
        <td class="label">Branch Number:
            <input type="text" name="branch" >                  
        </td>       
    <td>
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </td>
    </form>
 </table>
 </div>
</body>
```

and the JS:

```
function validateForm() {
  var x = document.forms["orderform"]["branch"].value;
  if (x == "") {
      alert("You must select a valid Branch branch");
      return; 
  } else {
    addData();
  }
}

function addData() {
    // di stuff here with your data
    alert('Everything is okay do stuff');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make just one function that is called on `submit` event. Inside that function call another one like your `validateForm()`. If you discover that something is wrong while validating, call `event.preventDefault()`/`event.returnValue = false` or just return `false` as you already know. Also if you want branch numbers to be numeric, use `isNumeric` function instead of just checking if it is an empty string.

```js
function isNumeric(n) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
function isDataValid(data) {
    // your checks...
    
    if (!isNumeric(data.branch)) return false;
    return true; 
}

function addData() {
   var e = event || window.event;
   var data = {};
   data.branch = document.forms["orderform"]["branch"].value;
   // other data
   // ...

   if(!isDataValid(data)) { 
       console.log("Data is invalid! The submit will not happen!");
       e.preventDefault();
   } else {
       // remove this else-branch later to make submit happen because the data in this case is valid
       console.log("Data is valid! The submit will happen!");
       e.preventDefault();
   }
}

document.getElementById("orderform").addEventListener('submit', addData, false);
```

```html
<div id = "divOrderuserinputContainer">
<table align="center" id="table">
    <form id="orderform" method="POST">          
        <td class="label">Branch Number:
            <input type="text" name="branch" ></input>                  
        </td>       
    <td>
        <input type="submit" value="submit"></input>
    </td>
    </form>
 </table>
 </div>
```

PS don't forget to handle cross-browserness `addEventListener/attachEvent`, `preventDefault/returnValue = false` etc. Also you could collect errors inside `isDataValid` and show them later to users in case they inserted something incorrectly.